# How does the CLR raise ThreadAbortException?

Tags: clr, threadabortexception

If you abort one managed thread from another, using Thread.Abort, how does the CLR actually throw the exception on the other thread?  Seems like a neat trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a few interesting links on the subject.  ThreadAbortException is a special case, and it is handled specially by the CLR.

http://mnikoo.net/2007/02/07/the-magic-of-the-clr-threadabortexception/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrteam/archive/2009/04/28/threadabortexception.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post on this awhile back.  The first part is about when a thread can be aborted, the second is about how it actually works.

I hadn't ever seen any correct (in this case, complete) documentation about how it actually works, so I wrote about about it.

The jist is that the CLR will use SetThreadContext (a win32 api) to hijack your current IP and move you into a special stub to set up the thread abort if you're thread isn't in an abortable wait.

[Check out the post here](http://www.steveniemitz.com/Blog/post/Threads-cant-be-aborted-while-theyre-running-code-inside-a-catchfinally-block.aspx)